# Jest test passes but .. has console message You are trying to access a property or method of the Jest environment after it has been torn down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

My test passes but has a console refrenceError:

**You are trying to access a property or method of the Jest environment after it has been torn down.**

Test:

```
import {render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import {create, act} from 'react-test-renderer';
import Comp1 from './Comp1';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

it('Should wait for response', () => {
    act(() => {
        waitFor(() => {
        render(<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}><Comp1 /></QueryClientProvider>);
        expect(screen.getByTestId('loading', {}, { timeout: 2000 })).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
});
```

Any Idea's? this checks the response of a async/await api call.

Answer (score 5):

Simply add `jest.useFakeTimers();` after import statements in your test file

Answer (score 2):

It's an async issue, you need to add `async`, `wait`:

```js
it('Should wait for response', async () => {
  render(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Comp1 />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );

  await waitFor(() => {
        expect(screen.getByTestId('loading', {})).toBeInTheDocument();
   });
});
```

=== EDIT ===

you may use `findBy()` instead (already includes the `waitFor()`) cleaning up the test:

```js
it('Should wait for response', async () => {
  render(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Comp1 />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );

  const loading = await screen.findByTestId('loading')
  expect(loading).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by use of async methods in a helper function without using `await` properly.

We had extracted some business logic for navigation into a help function, but when we copied over the code we didn't turn it into an async method.

For instance, we were using `waitFor` without any promises or `await`, so the context would be accessed after the environment was torn down and this caused an issue.

Check your helpers, test setup, and other uses of async methods if you're seeing this error. Even if they're nested, it could certainly be the problem.